# Law of Demeter - The pragmatic programmer

Tags: law-of-demeter

I have some questions considering the exercises in "the pragmatic programmer".

It says:

1.

```
public void showBalance(BankAccount acct) {
Money amt = acct. getBalance() ;
printToScreen(amt .printFormat()) ;
}
```

> The variable acct is passed in as a parameter, so the getBalance call is allowed. Calling
>   amt.printFormat(), however, is not. We don't "own"amt and it wasn't passed to us.

But we *do* own amt right? It is declared in the method and the LOD states: When your method creates local objects, that method can call methods on the local objects.

Is this example breaking the LOD? The way I see it, it isn't?

2.

```
public class Colada {
private Blender myBlender;
private Vector myStuff;

public Colada() {
myBlender = new Blender();
myStuff = new Vector() ;
}

private void doSomething() {
myBlender.addlngredients(myStuff.elements());
}
}
```

> Since Colada creates and owns both myBlender and myStuff, the calls to addIngredients and
>   elements are allowed .

Now I don't understand why doSomething is allowed to make calls to myBlender and myStuff since it didn't create it.

3.

```
void processTransaction(BankAccount acct, int) {
Person *who;
Money amt;
amt.setValue(123.45);
acct.setBalance(amt);
who = acct .getOwner() ;
markWorkflow(who->name(), SET_BALANCE);
}
```

> In this case, processTransaction owns amt, it is created on the stack, acct is passed in, so both setValue and setBalance are allowed. But processTransaction does not own who, so the call
>   who->name() is in violation.

So here it does declare who but it is not allowed to make calls to it. Perhaps I misunderstand the concept of "owns".

Can someone please clarify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the supposed contradictions one by one.

1.

```
public void showBalance(BankAccount acct) {
    Money amt = acct. getBalance() ;
    printToScreen(amt .printFormat()) ;
}

The variable acct is passed in as a parameter, 
so the getBalance call is allowed. 
Calling amt.printFormat(), however, is not. 
We don't "own" amt and it wasn't passed to us.
```

This statement is perfectly valid, since LoD states that while `acct` can be passed to `showBalance()` and `showBalance()` can access `getBalance()` due to having a direct reference to `acct`, it may not call any method on any instance of `Money`. This is because no object of type `Money` was passed to `showBalance()`, and it merely referred to it through a local accessor. This does not mean that the ownership of `amt` is now with `showBalance()`.

2.

```
public class Colada {
    private Blender myBlender;
    private Vector myStuff;

    public Colada() {
        myBlender = new Blender();
        myStuff = new Vector() ;
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        myBlender.addlngredients(myStuff.elements());
    }
}

Since Colada creates and owns both myBlender and myStuff, 
the calls to addIngredients and elements are allowed .
```

Now, what is happening in this class constructor is the declaration and instantiation of a `Blender` and a `Vector` object. Therefore, the owner of `myBlender` and `myStuff`, is the class `Colada`. LoD states that a method `m` of object `o` can access all direct components of `o`, so in this case, method `doSomething()` has access to `Colada`'s components directly, and it may call methods of `Blender` and `Vector` on `myBlender` and `myStuff`.

3.

```
void processTransaction(BankAccount acct, int) {
    Person *who;
    Money amt;
    amt.setValue(123.45);
    acct.setBalance(amt);
    who = acct .getOwner() ;
    markWorkflow(who->name(), SET_BALANCE);
}

In this case, processTransaction owns amt, 
it is created on the stack, acct is passed in, 
so both setValue and setBalance are allowed. 
But processTransaction does not own who, 
so the call who->name() is in violation.
```

The method `processTransaction()` receives the the bank account in object `acct`. It initializes an object of type `Money`, sets the value and then calls the setter method `setBalance()` on acct, which is in line with LoD. Since `amt` was created and initialized inside `processTransaction`, access to `setValue` of `amt` is also in line with LoD. Now comes the contradiction. `*who` is merely a pointer to an object of type `Person`, which is only visible through the accessor method `getOwner`. But that method is owned by `acct`, so calling a method on `*who` is invalid, as it breaks LoD.

In short, LoD states that `a.getB().getC().doSomething()` is invalid, and only `a.getB()` is valid. If I have to write LoD in plain English, it can be specified in 3 words - `Chain Of Command`.

Assuming a hierarchy where `Object A` contains an instance of `Object B`, and `Object B` contains an instance of `Object C`, the following hold true according to LoD.

- Object A cannot access and change Object C through an instance of Object B.
- Object B can, however, access and change Object C based on some criteria that it can fetch from Object A.

I hope that clears your doubts.

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting to understand it now. In the first example it's actually b = a.getBalance; b.printC; So equivalent to a.getB.printC. Also interesting for understanding LoD: [Demeter](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf)